# Change selected side in Taking Sides quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I was younger (and stupider) I did the quest Taking Sides but I choose Stormcloaks. Now I regret that decision very very much because I have to attack Whiterun.
I'm playing on Xbox360, is there any way to join the Imperials?

Comment: also, here's a wiki article with a flowchart: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Civil_War

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't any way to swap over to the other side once you have decided.

You would have to go back and create a new character and go through the process of joining the Imperials.

However there are some that say (During the Jagged Crown quest though, you can bring the crown to the other person and change sides by that.) So it might be worth attempting to do it that way.